# Передача DataTable в процедуру

Tags: c#, sql

Есть SQl процедура, которая принимает на вход таблицу.
Я передаю в коде C# DataTable в качестве параметра.
Подскажите, а можно задать в явном виде, какую колонку из пользовательского типа соотносить с колонкой DataTable?
Я боюсь, что как бы не поломалось ничего если поменяют колонки местами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Никак. Колонки должны идти в правильном порядке, иначе все поломается.

Но если обращаться к колонкам не по номерам, а по названиям - то порядок колонок перестанем быть важным для программы.

---

При использовании же `DbDataAdapter` можно отображать одни имена колонок в другие при помощи свойства `TableMappings`. Но у не уверен, что с его же помощью можно переставлять колонки местами.